# Ruby on Rails: CPU 100% and server crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I have 8 core/ 16GB RAM server. 
But when i test load on this server. the cpu reached 100% and crash in between process.
my landing page send 250+ HTTP requests/user.
the server is configured with nginx.
please comment required detail, i will edit this post.

Comment: I think you yourself mentioned one of the problems, 250+ requests/user for landing page. Can you provide more context/post code?

Comment: How does your load test look like? What tool do you use? How does the does of the tested route look like? How does you application's production.log look like? Is it the Rails application that cashes or the nginx? Any information in the system log file?